# Can i create table with grant to specific role on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have permission to create/drop table but don't have permission to grant table to any role.
So when I create table on server I can't select from it.

Is there anyway to create table and specific grant to any role in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

Grant permission to create tables to a specific user in a specific database not only requires `CREATE` `TABLE` permissions but also requires `ALTER` permissions to the schema.

```
GRANT ALTER ON Schema :: schema-name TO DATABASENAME
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO DATABASENAME
```

Comment: I already have permission to create a table but I can't select from it because role that I was assigned to is specific table that can be access.

So I want to know if I can create table with specific grant that table to any role.